# vkCreateShaderModule doesn't fail, even when pCode doesn't point to valid SPIR-V code

Tags: vulkan

By the documentation, the `pCode` field of the `VkShaderModuleCreateInfo` struct

> must point to valid SPIR-V code, formatted and packed as described by the Khronos SPIR-V Specification.

Now, I've made a typo in the call of the following utility function and unintendedly provided the file name of the GLSL code as the `shader_file_name`.

```
void create_shader_module(VkDevice device, std::string const& shader_file_name)
{
    std::ifstream shader_file(shader_file_name, std::ios::binary);

    shader_file.seekg(0, std::ios_base::end);
    std::size_t const shader_file_size = shader_file.tellg();

    if (shader_file_size > 0)
    {
        assert(shader_file_size % sizeof(std::uint32_t) == 0);

        std::vector<char> binary(shader_file_size);
        shader_file.seekg(0, std::ios_base::beg);
        shader_file.read(binary.data(), shader_file_size);

        VkShaderModuleCreateInfo shader_module_create_info{};
        shader_module_create_info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SHADER_MODULE_CREATE_INFO;
        shader_module_create_info.codeSize = shader_file_size;
        shader_module_create_info.pCode = reinterpret_cast<std::uint32_t const*>(binary.data());

        VkShaderModule shader_module;
        if (vkCreateShaderModule(device, &shader_module_create_info, nullptr, &shader_module) != VK_SUCCESS)
            throw std::exception("Could not create shader module");
    }
}
```

Despite the typo, the code didn't throw, i.e. `vkCreateShaderModule` returned `VK_SUCCESS`. Why?

(Note that a subsequent call to `vkCreateGraphicsPipelines` with a `VkPipelineShaderStageCreateInfo` which uses the generated shader module fails.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using Vulkan, not OpenGL. In Vulkan, it is not up to the implementation to validate your SPIR-V code. The Valid Usage for `vkCreateShaderModule` says that "`pCode` must point to valid SPIR-V code, formatted and packed as described by the
Khronos SPIR-V Specification." As with any other Valid Usage statement, if you violate it, the implementation will not tell you that you have done so.

You simply get undefined behavior.

Comment: True. Ideally the validation layers would have warned you about this, if you had them enabled. They do run the SPIR-V validator, but they might do that at pipeline creation time since some things can only be validated then; they could at least do basic validity checks at module creation time though.

Answer (score 3):

The validation layers would have found this problem, emitting a message:

> SPIR-V module not valid: Invalid SPIR-V magic number.

Ths validation layers run the SPIR-V validator at `vkCreateShaderModule` time.